# Using RtAudio with Core-Audio, the probeDeviceOpen function fails

Tags: c++, audio, core-audio

I am trying to write a C++ program which plays real-time processed audio. I have decided to use RtAudio but cannot make the test programs play audio.

I am using Mac OS X, so I compiled with `./configure --with-core` and `make`. After compiling the files in the test directory, I ran `./audioprobe` to return this list.

```
Compiled APIs:
  OS-X Core Audio

Current API: OS-X Core Audio

Found 3 device(s) ...

Device Name = Apple Inc.: Built-in Microphone
Probe Status = Successful
Output Channels = 0
Input Channels = 2
Duplex Channels = 0
This is NOT the default output device.
This is NOT the default input device.
Natively supported data formats:
  32-bit float
Supported sample rates = 44100 48000 88200 96000 

Device Name = Apple Inc.: Built-in Input
Probe Status = Successful
Output Channels = 0
Input Channels = 2
Duplex Channels = 0
This is NOT the default output device.
This is the default input device.
Natively supported data formats:
  32-bit float
Supported sample rates = 44100 48000 88200 96000 

Device Name = Apple Inc.: Built-in Output
Probe Status = Successful
Output Channels = 2
Input Channels = 0
Duplex Channels = 0
This is the default output device.
This is NOT the default input device.
Natively supported data formats:
  32-bit float
Supported sample rates = 44100 48000 88200 96000
```

Since the Built-in Output device is index 2, I then ran `./playsaw 2 44100 2`, but an error occurred:

```
RtApiCore::probeDeviceOpen: system error (kAudioHardwareUnknownPropertyError)
    getting stream format for device (2).
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on Lion (10.7)? I am seeing the same problem, on older systems (10.6.x) RtAudio work fine for me.

Perhaps you can downgrade to RtAudio 4.0.6, this worked for me on Lion, but there's still a bug lurking around with device names which got fixed in 4.0.8.

Comment: I thought this question would never be answered, but this seems to solve the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: seems the 4.0.10 fixed the problem.